# Configure Python Path for multiple folders in one Visual Studio Code workspace file

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

I have added 2 Python projects to one Visual Studio Code workspace. Now I want to configure the Python Path for both projects inside the workspace file. My folder structure is like this:

```
Root
    - venv (Virtual Environment)
    - Project One
    - Project Two
    - app.code-workspace (workspace file)
```

My workspace configuration file looks like the following:

```
{
    "folders": [
        {
            "path": "Project One"
        },
        {
            "path": "Project Two"
        }
    ],
    "settings": {
        "python.testing.unittestArgs": [
            "-v",
            "-s",
            ".",
            "-p",
            "*_test.py"
        ],
        "python.testing.pytestEnabled": false,
        "python.testing.nosetestsEnabled": false,
        "python.testing.unittestEnabled": true,
        "python.pythonPath": "venv/bin/python"
    }
}
```

But if I open a Python file in one of the project folders, it tells me to select a Python environment and then creates an separate `.vscode` folder with a `settings.json` in that project directory.

But I just want to use the settings of the workspace file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can the add the entire *Root* folder into the workspace, create the *.vscode* folder under *Root*, then specify the `python.pythonPath` in the *settings.json* in *Root/.vscode*, which will become applied to all the folders under *Root*.

Directory Structure:

```
├── Root
    ├── .vscode
    │   └── settings.json
    ├── Project\ One
    │   └── one.py
    └── Project\ Two
        └── two.py 
├── app.code-workspace
```

*app.code-workspace*

```
{
    "folders": [
        {
            "path": "Root"
        }
    ]
}
```

*.vscode/settings.json*

```
{
    "python.pythonPath": "/Users/gino/.virtualenvs/app/bin/python"
}
```

The final result will look like:

[image: vs code workspace]

All the Python files now in all "*Project X*" folders will now use the same `python` version. If you need to apply other settings, you can also add them to the *Root/.vscode/settings.json* file.