# VS Code (Windows) workspace with multiple editable python packages

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

I have a VS Code (1.83.1) workspace with multiple folders each containing a python package.

```
-Package1
--ClassA
-Package2
--ClassB
```

Package1 and Package2 are both packages I'm developing, but Package2 uses the modules in Package1, among other modules. I have installed Package1 in the virtual environment for Package2 with the following command (I added the editable_mode recently to see if it helped...it did not).

```
pip install -e c:\\users\\user\\GitLab\\modules --config-settings editable_mode=strict
```

If I'm editing within ClassB, then open ClassA, the Intellisense or syntax highlighting (language server?) immediately stops working and all text goes white for that ClassA package. The functionality seems to continue in Package2 just fine.

If I restart VS Code, everything works until I do the same above actions. If I only ever view Package1 and ClassA or other Package1 entities, it continues to work. It only seems to cause grief for Package1.

I tried looking at the Extension Logs for the Python language server and added the following to my User settings.json to increase verbosity, but nothing jumps out as an error like I was hoping:

```
"python.analysis.logLevel": "Trace",
```

imports "working"

[image]

imports "broken"

[image]

If I restart the Python language server:
[image]
functionality is restored

I noticed that if I use `"python.analysis.extraPaths"` in Package2, pointing to the directory for Package1, it causes code in Package1 to stop being parsed properly. It seems like perhaps there's a collision of name spaces or something similar.

I created a new workspace, and only added Package1 and Package2 directories as roots. When I did that, I noticed that when I CTRL+clicked a Package1 entity from Package2, it took me to the `build` sub-folder that was generated during the editable pip install:

```
C:\Users\user\gitlab\modules\build\__editable__.modules-0.0.5-py3-none-any\...
```

and the text was unparsed as I saw earlier in my other workspace.

Back in my original workspace, I still see the issue. If I manually open the proper location from the file explorer, the parsing takes place as expected.

Comment: You definitely do not want to install the packages you are using into project's virtual environment.  You just need to make sure that the directory containing the Package1 and Package2 directories are in your PYTHONPATH.  Having the package in your path twice is likely confusing VSCode.

Comment: hmm, I see what you're referring to...PYTHONPATH had not occurred to me nor come up in my searches. Let me try that

Comment: So I made the change, so I can import my modules from any environment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found out my primary issue seems related to multi-root VS code workspace. When I constructed a workspace referencing a single root folder, which contained all the packages I was editing, ALL issues around linking, finding, and editing packages worked immediately.

The tip for using `"python.analysis.extraPaths"` in the root location `.vscode/settings.json` does avoid the issue of needing to use editable installs for packages in development.

As a result, my solution is similar to these existing articles and considerations:

[Configure Python Path for multiple folders in one Visual Studio Code workspace file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58238934/configure-python-path-for-multiple-folders-in-one-visual-studio-code-workspace-f)

https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/multi-root-workspaces

Answer (score 0):

You can try to add the following codes to your settings.json to gain intellisense:

```
  "python.analysis.extraPaths": [
    "path/to/your/classA"
  ],
```

Comment: I already tried that near the bottom of the post. I've discovered it really seems to be an issue with multi-root workspaces in VS Code. The other python fixes suggested work well when there is a single root in the VS Code workspace.

Comment: Hi Brian, glad to know you've found the solution to resolve this issue! Please consider answering it and accepting it as an answer to change its status to Answered. See [can I answer my own question..](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer), Just a reminder :)

Comment: to followup, while that IS a useful method for libraries that are used in a workspace, it alone did not resolve my issue.